# why is an array fetched from backend not in the same order in redux store (react app)?

Tags: react-redux, redux-thunk

In my React app, i am fetching an array of posts from a backend api (nodejs/SQL DB).
I am using redux for the frontend, so i thought it would be a good idea to sort the posts on the backend and send them to the frontend (sorted by id, from latest to oldest).
Then, the array of posts gets stored in my redux store.

It's working fine, but i am confused because when i check the store, the posts are not ordered anymore, or rather: the same 4 random posts always get "pushed" to the top and then the rest is ordered as i wanted.
So when i refresh the page i can see these older random posts in the UI at the top of the thread/feed of posts and when component is fully mounted it renders posts in the correct order. Not good.

I wanted to avoid sorting the array of posts on the frontend for performance concerns, am i wrong?

Redux initial state:

```
const initialState = {
  posts: [],
  userPosts: [],
  currentPost: {
    title: "",
    text: "",
    imgUrl: "",
  },
  scrapedPost: {},
  comments: [],
  replies: [],
  likes: [],
  error: "",
  lastPostAdded: null,
  lastReplyAdded: null,
  lastDeleted: null,
  sessionExpired: false,
  users: [],
};
```

Redux root reducer:

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import { postsReducer } from "./posts.reducer.js";
import { userReducer } from "./user.reducer.js";

export const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  user: userReducer,
  posts: postsReducer,
});
```

Redux store config:

```
import { applyMiddleware, createStore } from "redux";
import { composeWithDevTools } from "redux-devtools-extension";
import { persistReducer, persistStore } from "redux-persist";
import autoMergeLevel2 from "redux-persist/lib/stateReconciler/autoMergeLevel2";
import storage from "redux-persist/lib/storage";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import { rootReducer } from "./reducers/root.reducer";

const composeEnhancer = composeWithDevTools({ trace: true, traceLimit: 25 });

const persistConfig = {
  key: "root",
  storage,
  stateReconciler: autoMergeLevel2,
};

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);
const store = createStore(persistedReducer, composeEnhancer(applyMiddleware(thunk)));
const persistor = persistStore(store);
export { store, persistor };
```

getPost action creator (using thunk middleware for async task):

```
export const getPosts = () => async (dispatch) => {
  const accessToken = localStorage.getItem("jwt");
  const request = {
    headers: {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
    },
    method: "get",
  };
  try {
    const response = await fetch(API_POST, request);
    const data = await response.json();
    const { posts, likes, sessionExpired } = data;
    if (sessionExpired) {
      dispatch({ type: SESSION_EXPIRED, payload: sessionExpired });
      return;
    }
    dispatch({ type: GET_POSTS, payload: { posts, likes } });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({ type: SET_ERROR_POST, payload: error.message });
  }
}
```

the posts reducer:

```
export const postsReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_POSTS: {
      const { posts, likes } = action.payload;
      return { ...state, posts, likes };
    }
    case GET_LIKES: {
      const { likes } = action.payload;
      return { ...state, likes };
      // all other actions...//
    }
```

relevant part of the UI code (feed component):

```
const Feed = () => {
  const [newUser, setNewUser] = useState(false);
  const user = useSelector((state) => state.user);
  const { isAuthenticated, isNewUser } = useSelector((state) => state.user);
  const posts = useSelector((state) => state.posts.posts);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const userLanguage = useLanguage();

  useEffect(() => {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    setNewUser(isNewUser);
    return function cleanup() {
      setNewUser(null);
    };
  }, [isNewUser]);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getPosts());
  }, []);

  return (
    <Layout>
    //some jsx...//
     <button className="h-6 refreshBtn outline-none hover:cursor-pointer    bg-blue-500 
      text-white rounded-full gap-1 flex items-center justify-center pl-2 pr-3 py-1 
      shadow transition-all duration-300 hover:bg-black hover:shadow-none group"
      onClick={() => dispatch(getPosts())}
      style={{ opacity: posts && posts.length !== 0 ? 1 : 0 }}>
         <RefreshIcon className="h-4 w-4 pointer-events-auto transform transition 
          transform duration-500 group-hover:-rotate-180" />
         <span className="text-xs pointer-events-auto capitalize"> 
            {userLanguage?.feed.refreshBtn}</span>
      </button>
      <div className="posts-wrapper h-full w-full relative flex flex-col items-center 
       justify-center gap-4 pb-6">
       {posts.length === 0  
        ? (<Skeleton element="post" number={8} />) 
        : (posts.map((post) => <Post key={post.postId} post={post} />)}
      </div>
    </Layout>
};
```

posts ordered by Id on the backend:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oh0rB.png)

posts in the redux store (as you can see by their postId, indexes 0 to 3 have nothing to do there)
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U23OZ.png)

so my questions:

- how come the array fetched is not in the same order in redux store?
- why does the UI flash the "wrong" order for a sec, then the correct order? how does it know the correct order if those 4 posts are still at the top in the store?

i'm confused here, any hint or help is appreciated! thanks

Comment: Have you checked your request response in network tab in devtools? It looks like the posts are sent in s erong order rather than shuffled in react. Also, I wouldn't be concerned about sorting on the frontend if you have less than 10000 posts and you don't do it every frame.

Comment: @KonradLinkowski thanks for the tip! i just checked the response in network and the posts are in the correct order, same as server side! This is really strange..
Is it bad practice to sort the data on the server side rather than on the frontend?

Comment: It's  actually a good practice to sort data on the backend side. I just wanted to tell that sometimes sorting on the frontend is ok and it's not as much resource demanding as one could think. I looked through your code and I have no idea why the posts are added on top :(

Comment: thanks a lot for your input though! @KonradLinkowski i'll keep investigating. i think it has to do with redux state/shallow merge or something.. let's see! ;)

Comment: `useSelector((state) => state.posts.posts)` your state seems to not be nested in this way. Why is there `posts.posts`?

Comment: oh that's because i named the posts reducer "posts" so i have to select state.posts.posts, state.posts.likes etc...

Comment: Can you show where do you use this postReducer? It seems like this can be a reason and there is some missing code in the post

Comment: @KonradLinkowski i just edited my question and added the code for the root reducer (where i use the postsReducer) + the config of the store, maybe i made a mistake somewhere, indeed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution months ago but forgot to come back here to give the solution to the issue i had.
Turns out the order of the posts fetched from backend wasn't modified or messed up with by Redux at all but by me (of course!) from another component called `PopularPosts`.
Consider the code below:

```
const PopularPosts = () => {
  const { posts } = useSelector(state => state.posts);
  const [top3, setTop3] = useState<IPost[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTop3(posts.sort((a, b) => { my sorting logic }).splice(0, 3));
  }, [posts]);
```

I was literally mutating the store directly in order to create my top3. Of course this was a HUGE mistake! I should have used the `sort()` method on a COPY of the store, not the store itself.

Here is the correct code:

```
const PopularPosts = () => {
  const { posts } = useSelector(state => state.posts);
  const [top3, setTop3] = useState<IPost[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const postsCopy = [...posts];
    setTop3(postsCopy.sort((a, b) => { // my sorting logic }).splice(0, 3));
  }, [posts]);
```

All is working as intended since this correction.
And lesson learnt: i'll never mutate the Redux store directly ever again ;)